# how to set timeout to playback in AVPlayer

Tags: swift, avplayer

I need help:

1. what is the default AVPlayer time out?
2. how to set timeout to playback in AVPlayer?
   I don't find any relevant info about it

Answer (score 1):

[AVPlayer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayer) does not have a method named stop. You can `pause` or set `rate` to `0.0`.